# CosmosDB Change feed: not fetching previous records even though StartFromBeginning is true

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

CosmosDB Change feed: not fetching previous records even though StartFromBeginning is true. I am using below sample to read change feed
https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/tree/master/samples/code-samples/ChangeFeedProcessorV2
Same Code is working with previous version 1.3.2

Comment: Did you already have leases and some progress done in document processing when you set `StartFromBeginning` to `true`

Comment: No. I tried after deleting the lease. I also tried by starting and stopping the App. It is only picking the changes which are done when the app is running. Before starting of the app and when app is under maintenance those changes are not coming.

Comment: Have you set the `ChangeFeedOptions.StartTime` to be in the past as well? It should automatically do it but just in case.

Comment: Yes I have tried tthis as well. "feedOptions.StartTime = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromHours(5);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are setting the `StartFromBeginning` on the `ChangeFeedProcessorOptions`:

```
ChangeFeedProcessorOptions feedProcessorOptions = new ChangeFeedProcessorOptions();
feedProcessorOptions.StartFromBeginning = true;
```

`ChangeFeedOptions` is no longer used in CFP 2.0 as per the [official repo notification on obsolete parameters](https://github.com/azure/azure-documentdb-changefeedprocessor-dotnet#note-on-obsolete-api).